# Difference in AWK when using NR with and withou print

Tags: awk, text-processing, text-parsing

I am a AWK beginner and after playing around with the built-in variable NR, I do not understand the following
Text:

```
CREDITS,EXPDATE,USER,GROUPS
99,01 jun 2018,sylvain,team:::admin
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
```

using

```
awk 'NR' file 
CREDITS,EXPDATE,USER,GROUPS
99,01 jun 2018,sylvain,team:::admin
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team

awk '{print NR}' file 
1
2
3
4
```

Thus, I was expecting to the same results when using NR>2&&NR<5. Here is what I got:

```
awk 'NR>2&&NR<5' file
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team
52,01    dec   2018,sonia,team

awk '{print NR>2&&NR<5}' file
Nothing shows up
```

Could you tell me why isn´t the last line showing a count from the numbers to 3 to 4 as it is displayed when using awk '{print NR}' file? It is not possible to mix a range of NR with the command print?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: try `awk '{print (NR>2&&NR<5)}' file` and `awk 'NR>2&&NR<5 {print NR}' file`.

Comment: Hello Gordon. The first attempt gave some strange results, a couple of zeros and ones, whereas the second attempt perfectly printed what I was looking for. Could you explain to me why you have to use NR again when using {print}? In the first example I didn´t have to use it in order to simply get my numbers, so why does it have to use in this case?

Comment: You might want to invest in some white space a parentheses when writing code. It makes your code clearer and less error prone. Try writing `print ( (NR>2) && (NR<5) )` instead of `print NR>2&&NR<5` and notice the difference in both functionality and clarity (what you currently have should really be flagged as a syntax error but it's also undefined behavior so YMMV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk 'NR>2&&NR<5' Input_file` is where we are checking condition if line number is greater than 2 and greater than 5 then do default action which is printing current line.

In you code `awk '{print NR>2&&NR<5}' Input_file`, here you are using print  and then mentioning condition which is NOT the way awk works.

***awk works on method of:***

```
Condition_check/regexp{action}
```

if NO action is given then by default print of current line will happen, which is happening in your first code.

***More analysis:***
To prove point `{print NR>2&&NR<5}` will NOT behave like default method of `awk` of `regexp/condition_check{action}` run this:

```
awk '{print (NR>2&&NR<5)}' Input_file
```

See the output what it will provide:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

See line 3rd and 4th which is `1` means condition for that line is TRUE and `0`  means condition for that line is FALSE. So by this we could see it prints condition's STATE in `print` statement if we use condition in `(..)` like mentioned above.